# How to Add Taxonomy Vocabulary in Rules when User Registers

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules

Using the Drupal Rules module, I'm trying to create a rule whereby when a user registers, a taxonomy vocabulary is created.

So far, I've done the following:

EVENT: After saving a new user account

ACTIONS: Create a new Entity, value Taxonomy vocabulary. I enter a name using tokens but it doesn't seem to accept tokens for the machine name. The machine name obviously has to be unique to each vocabulary.

Just to give you a bit more info, each member registering is a Tutor (needs to be the taxonomy vocabulary) and each Tutor will create multiple Students (taxonomy terms).

Can anyone help me with this please? I'm using Drupal 7. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the rules and I couldn't find a `Data Selector` for user name. But if you are fine with achieving the same using custom code then you can use the following code.

```
function YOURMODULENAME_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category){
   $vocabulary = new stdClass();
   $vocabulary->name = $account->name;
   $vocabulary->machine_name = "tutor_".$account->uid;
   $vocabulary->hierarchy = 0;
   taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocabulary);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me where I would put this code and I'll give it a go. I'm not familiar with adding code like this so any additional info I may need would be brilliant - thank you :)

Comment: You have to write a custom module and place the code there. [Here](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3674/how-to-create-a-custom-module-in-drupal-7) is a link explaining how to create a module.